# Как обработать код полученный с JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, gui, jtextfield

Проблема в том, что мне нужно обработать текст получаемый с окна ввода JTextField. Ошибка `Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'javax.swing.JTextField'`. На ввод подаются цифры от 0 до 9 и дальше я должен их закинуть в код. Думал обработать в Char, но не вышло.
Если строго указывать на ошибку то она здесь `jta = reader.readLine();`

```
        class alkashSP extends JFrame {
            JTextField jta = new JTextField(10);
            Font fnt = new Font("Times new roman", Font.BOLD, 25);

            alkashSP() {
                super("Input your cards. Like 2 5 6...");
                setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                setSize(300, 125);
                add(jta);
                jta.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                jta.setFont(fnt);
                JButton contButton = new JButton("Continue");
                contButton.setBounds(10, 40, 0, 10);
                add(contButton);
                jta.getText();
                contButton.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                        var sp = new Stack<Integer>();
                        var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                        String input = null;
                        try {
                            jta = reader.readLine();
                        } catch (IOException ioException) {
                            ioException.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        var split = input.split(" ");
                        for (var t : split)
                        {
                            sp.push(Integer.parseInt(t));
                        }


                    }
                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: `readLine()` возвращает строку, а вы приравниваете результат к текстовому полю. Я так понимаю, что вам всего лишь нужно заменить `jta` в этой строчку на `input`.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия помогло, спасибо